# html manipulation with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio, x-ray

I want to get html from a source (link or file , ...) and 
find values from it.
html format is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <main>
    <section id="serp">
      <div>
        <article>a</article>
        <article>b</article>
        <article>c</article>
        <article>d</article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

first of all i used [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).
according to docs i write:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(myhtml);
const content = $('#serp div').children();
console.log(content); // null
```

According to the same procedure i used [x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray) and jsdom but all of them 
print null.

Comment: What does `console.log(myhtml)` output, just before loading it in Cheerio?

Comment: it's string <!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <main>
    <section id="serp">
      <div>
        <article>a</article>
        <article>b</article>
        <article>c</article>
        <article>d</article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html> @JeremyThille

Comment: If the HTML is actually available and loaded into Cheerio, there's no reason why the selector should return null. The problem is elsewhere. Did you _actually_ try to log it, or did you say that because you think that's what would be logged?

Comment: @JeremyThille no i actually logged it

Comment: Hmmm that's strange, because the code is simple and there's really no reason why it shouldn't work. What if you select only `$('#serp')` ? Is it found?

Comment: log is => initialize(0) [] @JeremyThille

Comment: `initialize(0) []` ?? What the hell? Man, I have no clue what's going on here.

Comment: console.log($('#serp'));// it returns []

Comment: So what's `initialize(0)`? Whatever. It should find the element, not an empty array. I don't know...

Comment: excuse me. i use visual studio code and copy the its console text here and forgot to remove initialize(0) from it.

Comment: You're welcome, but I couldn't find the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the following:

```
let myhtml = `<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <main>
    <section id="serp">
      <div>
        <article>a</article>
        <article>b</article>
        <article>c</article>
        <article>d</article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>`;

const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(myhtml);
const content = $('#serp div').children();
console.log(content);
console.log(`html: ${content.html()}`);
```

it output the following to the console:

```
initialize {
  '0': 
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'article',
     namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
     attribs: {},
     'x-attribsNamespace': {},
     'x-attribsPrefix': {},
     children: [ [Object] ],
     parent: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'div',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     prev: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n        ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: null,
        next: [Circular] },
     next: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n        ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Circular],
        next: [Object] } },
  '1': 
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'article',
     namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
     attribs: {},
     'x-attribsNamespace': {},
     'x-attribsPrefix': {},
     children: [ [Object] ],
     parent: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'div',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     prev: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n        ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Circular] },
     next: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n        ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Circular],
        next: [Object] } },
  '2': 
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'article',
     namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
     attribs: {},
     'x-attribsNamespace': {},
     'x-attribsPrefix': {},
     children: [ [Object] ],
     parent: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'div',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     prev: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n        ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Circular] },
     next: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n        ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Circular],
        next: [Object] } },
  '3': 
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'article',
     namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
     attribs: {},
     'x-attribsNamespace': {},
     'x-attribsPrefix': {},
     children: [ [Object] ],
     parent: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'div',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     prev: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n        ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Circular] },
     next: 
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n      ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Circular],
        next: null } },
  options: 
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xml: false,
     decodeEntities: true },
  _root: 
   initialize {
     '0': 
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Object],
        parent: null,
        prev: null,
        next: null },
     options: 
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xml: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     length: 1,
     _root: [Circular] },
  length: 4,
  prevObject: 
   initialize {
     '0': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'div',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     options: 
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xml: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     _root: initialize { '0': [Object], options: [Object], length: 1, _root: [Circular] },
     length: 1,
     prevObject: initialize { '0': [Object], options: [Object], length: 1, _root: [Circular] } } }
html: a

Process finished with exit code 0
```